# How to change Material Color and Emission Color at Runtime

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to give a glow effect to my cubes in the game. I got success in applying glow effect in the cubes those are already present in the gameplay with different colors.

Below image to show you my current progress and represent my problem through graphics:
[image]

I want to change Normal and Emission Color of runtime spawned cubes and up to now I didn't able to get success.

I have tried this code:

```
    GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = cubeColors[cubeColorIndex];
    //GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.SetColor("_Color", cubeColors[cubeColorIndex]);
    GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.SetColor("_EmissionColor", cubeColors[cubeColorIndex] * 2f);
```

Through the above code, I can able to apply new emission color but still not get success in applying the main color to the cube material.
One more, what is the proper way to change the intensity of emission color?

This is how my cube inspector looks like:

[image]

Comment: the main color usually can be changed via `material.color = cubeColors[cubeColorIndex];` however .. your shader doesn't have a main color but a `base map` .. you would need to know the keyword the shader uses for it

Comment: yes, you are right its "_BaseColor" property to update so please post your reply as an answer and mentioned about "_BaseColor" too - what about emission intensity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first: In the shader you are using there is no `_Color` but the `_BaseColor` you want to set.

Second: You were almost there. In fact the emission intensity is just a multiplication but using [`Mathf.LinearToGammaSpace`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.LinearToGammaSpace.html)

```
var meshRenderer = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
var material = meshRenderer.material;

material.SetColor("_BaseColor", cubeColors[cubeColorIndex]);
material.SetColor("_EmissionColor", cubeColors[cubeColorIndex] * Mathf.LinearToGammaSpace(2f));
```

Comment: But I was already using Linear Color space for the project so what will be my Mathf function call ??

Comment: well did you try `* Mathf.LinearToGammaSpace(2f)` instead of `* 2f`?

Comment: LinearToGammaSpace can't able to create any glow effect around the cube.